# What is the return type of stack.top() and stack.pop() using stack<string> in cpp?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I am trying to print the return value of stack.top() using printf() of a stack but it is giving a format mismatch. The code is given below :

```
int main(){

    stack <string> cards;
    char *ch1;
    char ch2[20];
    cards.push("Ace");
    cards.push("King");
    cards.push("Queen");
    cards.push("Jack");
    printf("Number of cards : %ld \n", cards.size());

    ch1 = cards.top(); // As sizeof(cards.top()) is 8. error of type conversion
    strcpy(ch2,cards.top()); // cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char*’

    printf("Top of the Stack : %s \n", ch);
    return 0
}
```

In all examples I saw it was printed using "cout".

Comment: Simple solution: use `cout`, not `printf`.

Comment: You should get rid of all the char* and char[] and just use strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) is a different type from a `char*`, the following won't work:

```
ch1 = cards.top(); // top() returns a string, not a char*
```

I suggest using `std::string`s for your code:

```
int main(){

  stack <string> cards;
  string ch1; // std::strings
  string ch2;
  ...

  ch1 = cards.top(); // Correct

  printf("Top of the Stack : %s \n", ch1.c_str()); // c_str() needed
  return 0;
}
```

Also notice that using `printf` requires a `char*` type, you can get one with `std::string::c_str()`, or (even better) you can use `cout` in the first place:

```
std::cout << "Top of the Stack : " << ch1;
```

Therefore I'd suggest doing something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::stack <std::string> cards;
    std::string ch1;

    cards.push("Ace");
    cards.push("King");
    cards.push("Queen");
    cards.push("Jack in the Jack");

    std::cout << "Number of cards : " << cards.size() << std::endl;

    ch1 = cards.top(); // Get the top card

    std::cout << "Top of the Stack : " << ch1;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/VPrgwR)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The return value of is `pop` is `void`, `top` returns a reference to the data type that the stack holds. `std::string` is not the same as an array of `char` and it does not directly work with any of the C string functions. You can use `std::string::c_str()` to get the raw data, but it is better to stay in STL land. You can directly print `std::string` using `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strcpy`, which is a C function for C-style `char *` strings, for C++ `std::string`s - if you must use C strings for some reason then change:

```
strcpy(ch2,cards.top());
```

to

```
strcpy(ch2,cards.top().c_str());
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

This takes the `std::string` returned by `cards.top()` and returns a `const char *` which can be used by `strcpy`.

A better solution though would be to stick to C++ idioms throughout, i.e. use `std::string` exclusively and use `std::cout` instead of `printf` for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line

```
ch1 = cards.top();
```

`stack<string>::top()` returns `string`, while ch1 is `char *`. There is no type conversion from `string` to `char *`. To convert it, use the member function `c_str` :

```
ch1 = cards.top().c_str();
```

And ch1 must be `const char*`, not `char *`, because thats what `c_str` returns.

Why it returns `const char*` ? Because otherwise you could disrupt the string value by extracting `char *` and changing it.